# Compare files by names in c#

Tags: c#, pattern-matching, filenames

I have a routine that should compare files within a folder that have the following pattern:

```
path_to_file/some_common_base*.ext
```

where `path_to_file`, `common_base` and `.ext` must match, but the `*` part may change.

Now the problem I get is that in I might have `path_to_file` being with forward or backward slashes (`C:\\tmp\\...` or `C:/tmp/...`).

What is the suggested way to compare if a file matches the required pattern or not, in terms of performance and simplicity?

Comment: Use [Path.GetFilename](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) to just check against the filename (i guess that is the important part you must match). Or, probably better, [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It seems that `Path.GetFullPath("C:/Windows") == @"C:\Windows"`, so `Path.GetFullPath()` does a little path normalization...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the above comment, I ended up using the following approach, comparing the file names (which works as I know extensions):

```
string testingFile = "....";
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo("path_to_file");
foreach (FileInfo f in dir.GetFiles("*.ext")) {
    if (f.Name.ToUpperInvariant().StartsWith("some_common_base")) {
       // f is mathing requirement...
    }
}
```